# xPath selector does not work correctly

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I have a function to grab images `src` *attribute* in a `section` tag. but it give me images `src` out of **this specified section tag** (selected by `class`).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.akairan.com/health/bimari-behdasht/news201691911413397586.html');

$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$imgNodes = $finder->query('//article[@class="contentpaneopen_text"]//img/@src');

$images = array();
foreach($imgNodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . "<br />";
}
```

The result is:

```
http://cdn64.akairan.com/files/images/20160919/20169/2016919114132436510a.jpg
http://cdn2.akairan.com/akairan/telegram.jpg
http://ser8.akairan.com/img/cdn/125/30/icmjthidoctor.ir.jpg
http://ser9.akairan.com/img/cdn/180/80/akairan__aka__m998__027343234141194102a.jpg
http://ser9.akairan.com/img/cdn/180/80/akairan__aka__m998__074496544283135102a.jpg
```

But it should return just first link not the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are more than one `<img>` children inside `<article class="contentpaneopen_text">`, it's normal that you get more than one result.

Your xpath needs to be more precise. We can see that the one you want to match should also have a parent `<a>` and should have a `title` attribute.

try with:

```
//article[@class="contentpaneopen_text"]//a/img[@title!='']/@src
```

Comment: two last results are not inside <article class="contentpaneopen_text"> but showing in the results. this is my question. @Yann

Comment: They are actually inside `<article class="contentpaneopen_text">` because the tag not closed properly. try to dump the DOMDocument to a file and see for yourself using `$doc->saveHTMLFile('/tmp/file.html');` right after `loadHTMLFile `. `</article>` is badly placed after the two last results. Still, using the Xpath provided in my answer allows to only match the desired value.